# VHDL: Taking signals from one architecture to another

Tags: vhdl

Im trying to do a series of simple operations (multiplication, CA2, and, substraction) and then, based on the values of "sel", choose one of those possibilities, so essentially, a MUX, so far this is what I've got:
.vhd :

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity practica_8_ejercicio_2 is
    Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           sel : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           resultado : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end practica_8_ejercicio_2;


architecture mul3x3 of practica_8_ejercicio_2 is

--signal resultadomul3x3 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);

begin   

    resultado <= a * b;    
        
end mul3x3;

architecture rest33 of practica_8_ejercicio_2 is

--signal resultadorest33 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);

begin   

    resultado <= (a(3) & a(3)& a(3) & a(3) & a) - (b(3)& b(3) & b(3) & b(3) & b);    
           
end rest33;


architecture aCA2 of practica_8_ejercicio_2 is

--signal resultadoaCA2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);

begin   
    resultado <= (not (a(3) & a(3) & a(3) & a(3) & a)) + "00000001";   
           
end aCA2;


architecture aandb of practica_8_ejercicio_2 is

--signal resultadoand : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);

begin   
    resultado <= ("0000" & a) and ("0000" & b);    
          
end aandb;
```

testbench:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity practica_8_ejercicio_2_TB is
--  Port ( );
end practica_8_ejercicio_2_TB;





architecture mul3x3 of practica_8_ejercicio_2_TB is

component practica_8_ejercicio_2 is
    Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           sel : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           resultado : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end component;

signal T_a: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);      -- entrada 
signal T_b: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);      -- entrada 
signal T_sel: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);    --selector
signal T_resultado: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);   -- salida 
--signal T_resultadomul3x3 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);

begin

-- INSTANCIACIÓN -- 
ETIQUETA: practica_8_ejercicio_2 port map (a => T_a,
                       b => T_b,
                       sel => T_sel,
                       resultado => T_resultado);

estimulos:  process
begin


for I in 0 to 15 loop
                         T_a <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (TO_UNSIGNED(I,4));
                         T_b <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (TO_UNSIGNED(I,4));
                            wait for 1us;
                        end loop;
end process; 

end mul3x3;




architecture rest33 of practica_8_ejercicio_2_TB is

component practica_8_ejercicio_2 is
    Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           sel : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           resultado : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end component;

signal T_a: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);      -- entrada 
signal T_b: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);      -- entrada 
signal T_sel: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);    --selector
signal T_resultado: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);   -- salida 
--signal T_resultadorest33 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);

begin

-- INSTANCIACIÓN -- 
ETIQUETA: practica_8_ejercicio_2 port map (a => T_a,
                       b => T_b,
                       sel => T_sel,
                       resultado => T_resultado);

estimulos:  process
begin
T_sel <= "10";
for I in 0 to 15 loop
                         T_a <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (TO_UNSIGNED(I,4));
                         T_b <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (TO_UNSIGNED(I,4));
                            wait for 1us;
                        end loop;
end process; 

end rest33;








architecture aCA2 of practica_8_ejercicio_2_TB is

component practica_8_ejercicio_2 is
    Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           sel : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           resultado : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end component;

signal T_a: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);      -- entrada 
signal T_b: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);      -- entrada 
signal T_sel: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);    --selector
signal T_resultado: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);   -- salida 
--signal T_resultadoaCA2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);

begin

-- INSTANCIACIÓN -- 
ETIQUETA: practica_8_ejercicio_2 port map (a => T_a,
                       b => T_b,
                       sel => T_sel,
                       resultado => T_resultado);

estimulos:  process
begin
T_sel <= "01";
for I in 0 to 15 loop
                         T_a <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (TO_UNSIGNED(I,4));
                         T_b <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (TO_UNSIGNED(I,4));
                            wait for 1us;
                        end loop;
end process; 

end aCA2;









architecture aandb of practica_8_ejercicio_2_TB is

component practica_8_ejercicio_2 is
    Port ( a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           sel : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           resultado : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end component;

signal T_a: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);      -- entrada 
signal T_b: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);      -- entrada 
signal T_sel: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);    --selector
signal T_resultado: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);   -- salida 
--signal T_resultadoand : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);

begin

-- INSTANCIACIÓN -- 
ETIQUETA: practica_8_ejercicio_2 port map (a => T_a,
                       b => T_b,
                       sel => T_sel,
                       resultado => T_resultado);

estimulos:  process

begin
T_sel <= "00";                       
for I in 0 to 15 loop
                         T_a <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (TO_UNSIGNED(I,4));
                         T_b <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (TO_UNSIGNED(I,4));
                            wait for 1us;
                        end loop;
end process;                        

end aandb;
```

Problem is, that it seems like the selector defaults to "00", meaning that the only that its taken into account is the 'a and b', in fact, when I run the simulations, 'sel' has a constant value of 00 and the only thing with red dots in the testbench and in the .vhd is the part with the and operation.

So how should I go about making the MUX out of these 4 different architectures ? I would need to create with the 4 possible values of 'sel', and in each case, assign to 'resultado' the output of each operation. but since each output is in a separate architecture, I dont know how I should do it.
Forgot to mention, but those signals that are commented are the ones that I should use, but since they weren't doing anything for me at the moment, I commented them, but I'm supposed to have 1 signal for each output, and then I guess I should do something like this: resultado <= resultadomul3x3, but then again no idea how I should approach the situation with the MUX. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your four architectures implement 4 different versions of the entity, and all of them ignore the selector input.

As you have instantiated the entity in the TB without specifying WHICH architecture, the first matching one is selected.

You COULD add a fifth architecture, which instantiates the entity four times (each with a different architecture) and their outputs connected to four signals, which are the inputs to a multiplexer selecting the output you want.

```
architecture toplevel of practica_8_ejercicio_2 is

  signal result_0 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
  signal result_1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
  signal result_2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
  signal result_3 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);

begin   

    resultado <= result_0 when sel = "00" else
                 result_1 when sel = "01" else
                 -- ... etc

    arch0: entity work.practica_8_ejercicio_2(mul3x3) 
         port map (a => T_a,
                   b => T_b,
                   sel => T_sel,
                   resultado => result_0);

    arch1: entity work.practica_8_ejercicio_2(aca2) 
         port map (a => T_a,
                   b => T_b,
                   sel => T_sel,
                   resultado => result_1);
    -- etc
           
end toplevel;
```

That's doing it the hard way.

Personally I would just create one architecture containing the MUX and the four alternative actions.

```
architecture easy of practica_8_ejercicio_2 is
    
begin   

    resultado <=     a * b
                 when sel = "00" else
                     (a(3) & a(3)& a(3) & a(3) & a)
                     - (b(3)& b(3) & b(3) & b(3) & b) 
                 when sel = "01" else
                     (not (a(3) & a(3) & a(3) & a(3) & a)) + "00000001"                    
                 when sel = "10" else
                     ("0000" & a) and ("0000" & b);  
end easy;
```

(Are you trying to learn VHDL without a decent book?)